# Disable horizontal scrolling

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I am looking for a method/trick to DISABLE (not just hide) a horizontal scroll bar.  I have search all over and all I have found was "overflow-x:hidden". The issue with that is i have to drag an element from one div to another

im working on a jquery ui based page where a user can drag a div from one container to another container. the first side is dynamically populated with divs from the database. I need verticle scrolling because it's a dynamically populated list, but with horizontal scrolling enable it prevents the divs from being able to be dragged over to the droppable area.

Comment: can you please be more descriptive

Comment: Are you using jQuery to do dragging?

Comment: Please describe in more detail how `overflow-y:hidden;` doesn't do what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fairly common problem. Have a look at [this page](http://ccnmtl.columbia.edu/compiled/projects/clone_wars_jquery_ui_draggable.html). It describes a workaround To this problem by appending the draggable to a different element `ondragstart` and reappending it to its original container `ondragend`.

Comment: Sorry about that. I fixed the link.

Comment: I don't have enough enough reputation points to give this solution positive rank, but I totally would. 
The only thing I had to do was give it a helper clone, for my purposes. But that article is what got me thinking along that track. Thanx alot chuck!!!!

Answer (score 3):

You haven't said, so I will assume you are using jQuery to do dragging. In the [jQuery docs on Draggable](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Draggable), there is an option called 'scroll'. If you set it to false, draggable objects will not scroll the window.

Comment: I don't think that's part of the CSS3 standard, "visible|hidden|scroll|auto|no-display|no-content;" are listed.

Comment: there is no such thing as `overflow: none;`

Comment: That's true, I agree. The suggested edit said `overflow: hidden;`, which Matt Ryan said he had tried already. So, I changed to (hopefully) a more helpful answer. Thanks for pointing out my error.

Comment: ive added more info and a link to the page. thax for your help guys.

Comment: I still think you need to set the `scroll` option to false. It won't prevent scrolling the div altogether; it just prevents scrolling the div as your drag an element.

Comment: the scroll option is set to false.